# All records from first table and extra records from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2019

I have 2 tables where i want to take all records from 1st table and extra records from 2nd table.

Table A

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| ID  | NAME    | TASK    |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 101 | Alan    | Prepare |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 102 | Fabien  | Approve |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 103 | Christy | Plan    |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 104 | David   | Approve |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 105 | Eric    | Set     |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

Table B

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| ID  | NAME    | TASK    |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 101 | Richy   | Prepare |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 103 | Girish  | Plan    |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 106 | Fleming | Approve |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 107 | Ian     | Set     |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

Expected output

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| ID  | NAME    | TASK    |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 101 | Alan    | Prepare |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 102 | Fabien  | Approve |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 103 | Christy | Plan    |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 104 | David   | Approve |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 105 | Eric    | Set     |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 106 | Fleming | Approve |
+-----+---------+---------+
| 107 | Ian     | Set     |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

I have tried using `LEFT JOIN`. But i'm getting only all from left table.

```
select * from A left join B on A.ID=B.ID and B.ID is NULL
```

I have also tried `UNION` and `UNION ALL` but since `Name` can be different in 2 tables i'm getting both records.  One solution could be using `NOT IN` but it will be big for me as i refer big queries as table A & B here. I dont know what i'm missing.  It should be very simple but it is not striking me now. Please help.

Comment: Fleming and Ian do not exist in [A], therefore this is simply no way they will appear in the resultset as it is based on [A].  This join condition `A.ID=B.ID and B.ID is NULL` is logical nonsense. Joining on a column and then filtering for NULL in that same column will match nothing in [B] - effectively and logically you are not really joining at all. You should provide clear definitions of what your tables represent and what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking a union with the help of `ROW_NUMBER` and a computed column:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, NAME, TASK, 1 AS SRC FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, NAME, TASK, 2 FROM TableB
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SRC) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT ID, NAME, TASK
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The idea here is to build an intermediate table containing all records from both tables.  We introduce a computed column which keeps track of the table source, and give A records a higher priority than B records.  Using `ROW_NUMBER` allows us to select the A records over B records having the same `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

`Full outer join` will work, as full out join will get all the matching and non matching records from both the tables

```
;with tablea as 
(
select  101 as id,  'Alan'    name, 'Prepare ' as task
union select  102 , 'Fabien'  , 'Approve' 
union select  103 , 'Christy' , 'Plan    '
union select  104 , 'David'   , 'Approve '
union select  105 , 'Eric'    , 'Set   ')
,tableb as (
select  101 as ID  ,'Richy  ' as NAME   ,' Prepare ' as TASK     
union select  103 ,'Girish ',' Plan    '
union select  106 ,'Fleming',' Approve '
union select  107 ,'Ian    ',' Set '
)

select isnull(a.id,b.id) as id, isnull(a.name,b.name) as name, isnull(a.task,b.TASK) from tablea a
full outer join tableb b on a.id = b.ID
```

> Result

[image]